# Where to put data files for current user

Tags: windows, powershell

In Powershell, how do you find out where data files (just a few small files, if it matters) for the current user should be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would ApplicationData folder do?

It should be defined as an environment variable, so there is a variable

```
$env:APPDATA
```

If it isn't available, special folder can be queried too:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
```